# Show that $ \int f dx - \int g dx = \int(f-g)dx $

Tags: real-analysis

The following exercise is in the book Measure theory and Integration by G de Barra on page 60, is number 2 and says:

Let $f,g \ge 0$ be measurable, with $ f \ge g, \int g < \infty $. Show that $ \int f\mathrm{d}x - \int g \mathrm{d}x = \int(f-g)\mathrm{d}x$

I try to use the theorems in that section. Something like since $f$ and $g$ were both measurable $$ \int f \mathrm{d}x+ \int g \mathrm{d}x = \int(f+g)\mathrm{d}x $$ by theorem 6 and just use the fact that $\int cg \mathrm{d}x = c\int g\mathrm{d}x$  but appareantly that only works when $c>0$ and I missing the hypothesis that  $\int g < \infty$

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f =(f-g)+g$ so $\int f =\int(f-g)+\int g$. Since $\int g <\infty$ we can subtract $\int g$ from both sides to get $\int f -\int g=\int (f-g)$.